# passing elements to the node.js terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question, I read the documentation of the node but I continue with doubt.
Basically, I want to pass two parameters through the terminal before executing my script, and if these parameters are different from white, it will execute the script.
I came to read that process.argv would serve this purpose, but I did not understand how it would work for its implementation.
If anyone could help me with the answer I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.argv` is an array so you can't do `process.argv((inicio,fim) =>{...});`

For example, assuming the following script for process-args.js:

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});
```

Launching the Node.js process as:

```
$ node process-args.js one two=three four
```

Would generate the output:

```
0: /usr/local/bin/node
1: /Users/mjr/work/node/process-args.js
2: one
3: two=three
4: four
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to passing in arguments, you can set environment variables before running the app.

In powershell: `$env:COLOR="red"`

Then in your app you can say

```
if (process.env.COLOR != 'white') {
   //do logic
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Viva,

Instead of calling process.argv(), you can access the elements of the array as explained in the documentation and answer below. For your case in specific the following code should work:

```
  const alasql = require('alasql');
  const request = require ('request');
  const rp = require('request-promise')

  var inicio = process.argv[2];
  var fim = process.argv[3];

  if(inicio != "" && fim != ""){
  var i;
  var type = "day";
  var start = `${inicio}`
  var end = `${fim}`

  var arrayTalhao =[
            // Fazenda Estrela
              {nome:'Fazenda estrela',propertyId:'5b10926942996e0004d894a8', field:'5c0ff8211dc1d9922df9a342'},
            // Fazenda São Jose
              {nome:'Fazenda São Jose',propertyId:'5be95d1a1019e0af7a590726',field: '5c0ff8211dc1d9922df9a331'},
            // Fazenda Botelho
              {nome:'Fazenda Botelho',propertyId:'5bec17461019e0af7a5f9917',field:'5c0ff8211dc1d9922df9a332'},
            // Agricola Cruzinha
              {nome:'Agricola Cruzinha',propertyId:'5bf6ec9d1019e0af7a7b6973',field:'5c0ff8211dc1d9922df9a339'},
            // Nº senhora aparecida
              {nome:'Nº Senhora Aparecida',propertyId:'5c14154eb46519d806a0c145',field:'5c18e8a73108897f89d8de28'},
            //Fazenda Santa Erestina
            {nome:'Fazenda Santa Erestina',propertyId:'5c055c441019e0af7aa80d2e',field:'5c11165d798af7568e661d0f'},
            //Fazenda São Jose II
            {nome:'Fazenda São Jose II',propertyId:'5c080fe01019e0af7aaf4981',field:'5c0ff8211dc1d9922df9a343'},
            //Agropecuaria 7 Reis
            {nome:'Agropecuaria 7 Reis',propertyId:'5c108b0b1019e0af7ac39eb5',field:'5c11479a798af7568e661e5f'}  
  ] 
  var link = `http://test.agrointeli.com.br:4444/data/last?type=${type}&start=${start}&end=${end}&talhaoId=${arrayTalhao[0].field}&propertyId=${arrayTalhao[0].propertyId}`

  for(i=1; i<arrayTalhao.length; i++){
      var link = `http://test.agrointeli.com.br:4444/data/last?type=${type}&start=${start}&end=${end}&talhaoId=${arrayTalhao[i].field}&propertyId=${arrayTalhao[i].propertyId}`
      console.log(link)

      jsonxlm(link)
      async function jsonxlm(link){
      var nomeTalhao = (arrayTalhao[i].nome)
      console.log(arrayTalhao[i].nome)
      await rp(link, async function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        var content = JSON.parse(body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        teste = JSON.parse(body);
        content.map((item) =>{
          item._id = `${item._id.dia}/${item._id.mes}/${item._id.ano};`
        })
        alasql(`SELECT * INTO XLSX("${nomeTalhao}.xlsx", {headers: true}) FROM ?`, [content])
      })
    }
  }

  } else{
    console.log("Digite os parametros")
  }
```

You would execute like this: 
    node *script_name.js inicio fim